# JIRA rest/api/2 how to copy dashboard?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I use rest/api/2 to some work about jira dashboard.

but when I try copy dashboard, it always not fine.

my whole code is:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

def auth(name, password):
    return HTTPBasicAuth(name, password)

def copy_dashboard(auth, id, name):

    url = f"https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/dashboard/{id}/copy"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    payload = json.dumps({
        "description": "A dashboard to help auditors identify sample of issues to check.",
        "editPermissions": [],
        "name": name,
        "sharePermissions": [
            {
                "type": "global"
            }
        ]
    })

    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        url,
        data=payload,
        headers=headers,
        auth=auth
    )
    print(response.json())
```

then I call this fuction, but fail.

```
auth = auth("username", "password")
copy_dashboard(auth, 12221, "test_copy_dashboard")   # it return 404
```

it returns 404:

```
{'message': 'null for uri: https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/dashboard/12221/copy', 'status-code': 404}
```

I dont know whether my code itself as an error?

I dont know whether my code itself as an error?
or any other error I have not find...

Comment: I think in Jira server you'll have to get an existing dashboard and POST (create) a new one based on the existing one.

``` 
dashboard_url = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/2/dashboard/{dashboard_id}"
response = requests.get(dashboard_url, headers=headers)
dashboard_json = response.json()

dashboard_json["id"] = None
dashboard_json["name"] = "Copy of " + dashboard_json["name"]

# Create the copied dashboard using the Jira REST API
create_dashboard_url = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/2/dashboard"
create_response = requests.post(create_dashboard_url, headers=headers, json=dashboard_json)
```

Comment: thank you @Shachar297

your code looks like to get dashboard，and in my case，I get dashboard with rest/api/2 is ok，but copy dashboard fail.
do you have copy dashboard or create dashboard code example.
as supplementary，my company is use Jira Server/Data.

Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I think in Jira server you'll have to get an existing dashboard and POST (create) a new one based on the existing one.

```py
dashboard_url = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/2/dashboard/{dashboard_id}"
response = requests.get(dashboard_url, headers=headers) 
dashboard_json = response.json() 
dashboard_json["id"] = None 
dashboard_json["name"] = "Copy of " + 
dashboard_json["name"] # Create the copied dashboard using the Jira REST 
API create_dashboard_url = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/2/dashboard" 

# Execute create dashboard using POST.
create_response = requests.post(create_dashboard_url, headers=headers, json=dashboard_json)
```

I have just checked this code over our Jira and it works for me. Good luck !

In Jira cloud, you have the ability of copying dashboard using REST API using this endpoint

```
https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/dashboard/{id}/copy
```

worth checking this endpoint over the Jira server/DC before implementing other ways.

Comment: Thank you @Shachar297 

can you please tell me your jira environment is jira server or jira cloud？

my environment now is jira server, actually I have not found create/copy dashboard rest api in jira server's developer documentation.

I  have try your code, failed again.

Comment: I  have try your code, failed again.

1. to get dashboard is ok.
`dashboard_url = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/2/dashboard/{dashboard_id}" 
response = requests.get(dashboard_url, headers=headers) `


2. but to create dashboard returns <Response [405]>.

 `dashboard_json = response.json() 
 dashboard_json["id"] = None 
 dashboard_json["name"] = "Copy of " + dashboard_json["name"] 

 create_dashboard_url = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/2/dashboard" create_response = requests.post(create_dashboard_url, headers=headers, json=dashboard_json) `

Thank you very much for your reply.